# sql expression SUM(col1 + col2) / COUNT(1) other workaround

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any possibility that this expression will differ..(mainly 1 and 2)

```
 SUM(col1 + col2) / COUNT(1)             //1
```

and

```
 AVG(col1 + col2 )                       //2
```

and

```
 (SUM(col1) + SUM(col2)) / COUNT(1)      //3
```

and

```
(SUM(col1) + SUM(col2)) / COUNT(col1)    //4
```

and

```
(SUM(col1) + SUM(col2)) / COUNT(col2)    //5
```

Comment: Using numbers instead of columns is a bad idea. In any case, all `COUNT()` examples you posted are the same as `COUNT(*)`. As for different results, yes, the results will differ if either column contains a `null` because `col1+col2` will also be NULL

Comment: In case you think that `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)` - it's not. `count(1)` is actually slightly slower in Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example returns different result for each of your 5 cases:

```sql
with t(x,y) as (values(100,10),(200,20),(300,null),(null,40),(null,50),(null,null))
select count(*), count(1), count(x)
     , sum(x + y) / count(1)      
     , avg(x + y)                 
     , (sum(x) + sum(y)) / count(1)
     , (sum(x) + sum(y)) / count(x)
     , (sum(x) + sum(y)) / count(y)
from t
```

As @GordonLinoff said, it is because of null. (I didn't want to throw example away once it was created.)

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d1463c76cbf6c395bd591090c053e062)

Comment: Thanks for the example !

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  They differ based on `NULL` values in the columns.  And based on the types.

You don't specify the types, but in Postgres, Integer division returns an integer, whereas average will return a number with decimal places.

In fact, none of them are equivalent.

But, if the columns are never `NULL` then they are equivalent.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0238d3d355fbe82aeb406336c666d541) is a db<>fiddle illustrating differences.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff